# How to Clean up This Java Example Memory

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, finalize

I was reading about garbage collection and finalization in Java and when I tried an example. I click button 1, and memory jumps up. But when I click button 2, the memory didn't free up used space!
What did I do wrong and how do I free memory from unused objects?

As far as I know (I may be wrong):

1. When the same variable is re-instantiated again and again, the old object shall be destroyed.
2. When I set a variable to null the the old object shall be destroyed.
3. Array cells are null values. They shall be destroyed when parent array object has no variable to reference it.
4. How do I free up collections? How do array rules apply?

Code:

```
public class Memory extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Object[] object;

    private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        object = new Object[10240000];
    }

    private void Button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        object = null;

        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();

        //OR

        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if the GC collects an object, Java might still keep the memory to allocate new objects more efficiently.

Comment: How do you know that no space was freed up? It's likely that the GC did its work (the available heap space increased) but that the JVM itself did not release memory to the OS...

Comment: Also, setting variables to null is not what makes an object eligible to GC. An object becomes eligible to GC when it is not reachable by any strong reference chain from a root (thread stack or static variable). For example, if you do `Object a = new Object(); b = a; a = null;`, the object that was referenced by `a` won't be GCed because `b` still references it.

Comment: Use jvisualvm (bundled with JDK) to see that your free heap will be most probably be increased. (or enable GC logging (-verbose:gc)). So you can verify whether the GC actually cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.gc()` is only a suggestion for the JVM to clean up the memory. It may or may not take this suggestion. You are not doing anything wrong. Relax.

Comment: In practice it generally does what it's asked to do, and probably did in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Java will clean unused objects out eventually, that's what garbage collector is for. You don't have to worry about it or write any code for it.

GC in Java periodically and it is not instantaneous, System.gc() only suggests that GC should run, which might not happen.

If you want to see java GC in action you should try a program with longer run-time to see what's going on with memory and GC in action.

1. *When same variable is re-initanciated more and more the old object shall be destroyed.*
2. *When set a variable to null the the old object shall be destroyed*
3. *Array cells are null values they shall be destroyed when parent array object has no variable to reference it*
4. *How to free up collections or Array rules apply?*

Answer to all four points is: Garbage collector will take care of that.

Also the reason why memory is high even though the garbage collector probably did run is that JVM takes more memory than just the objects.

Comment: Make sure the asker knows that the GC runs periodically and it is not instantaneous, and to track memory usage in a busy Java app over a a period of time to get a better idea of it.